# How to Show Out of stock and discontinued items at last position in product listing

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

Can anyone please suggest on this .

I have more than 50k products in my website and I have created an attribute name "Discontinued Items" with yes/no option to show the product status like in stock or out of stock so there is no need to disable the products for SEO purpose if product is not longer exist in warehouse.

Now I want to list products in the below order at category page and search result page also product order  should be work with sort by filter(position, price, product name) options .

1. In stock Products
2. Out if stock Products
3. Discontinued Products

Currently I am using magento 2.2.3 version.

Can anyone please give the suggestion how it will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the products sort order for listing by using the custom observer on `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event.

I assume the "Discontinued Items" attribute code is `discontinued_items_flag`

**From admin you can perform below steps:**

go to Stores->Attributes->Product than click and edit your attribute.

> Used in Product Listing = Yes
>
> Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

Your observer code will be look like:

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

//If you have multi location inventory
//$websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$websiteId = 0;

/* For In/Out of stock Products */
$stockId = 'stock_id';
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('_inv' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')),
    "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId and _inv.stock_id=$stockId",
    array('stock_status')
);

$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());
$collection->getSelect()->reset('order');

$collection->addAttributeToSort('in_stock', 'DESC');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('discontinued_items_flag', 'ASC');
return $this;
```

To work with filter you can do like:

```
/* set __construct dependency for  \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request */
$sortOrder = $this->request->getParam('product_list_order');
$sortDir = $this->request->getParam('product_list_dir');
$sortDir = (empty($sortDir))?'ASC':$sortDir;

switch ($sortOrder) {
        case 'position':
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('in_stock', 'DESC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('discontinued_items_flag', 'ASC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('position', $sortDir);
        break;

        case 'name':
        //$finalSortOrder = 'name';
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('in_stock', 'DESC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('discontinued_items_flag', 'ASC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', $sortDir);
        break;

        default:
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('in_stock', 'DESC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('discontinued_items_flag', 'ASC');
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('position', $sortDir);
        break;
    }
```